# Azure Active Directory Custom Branded login page dont work with third party application

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I was wondering if its possible to use the new active directory custom login page preview with Third party applications? We are trying to make things work but we are only able to used to default login page. The custom login page seem to work with office365 and with the azure portals but not with custom application...

Answer (score 0):

Custom branding will only work when the sign-in URL contains the tenant identifier (usually the domain name). Since the multi-tenant app doesn't know that, it is likely this is why you don't see custom branding. From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn532270.aspx):

> **When will users see a branded sign-in page?**
>
> In the current preview, your users will see a branded page when they visit sites with a URL containing your domain name, such as https://outlook.com/contoso.com. This domain name must appear as “Active” in the Active Directory > Directory > Domains section of the Windows Azure management portal where you have configured branding.

Another way of seeing it is that, since you haven't signed in yet and the application isn't yours, there's no way for Azure AD to know who's custom branding to show. When you go to outlook.com/*(yourdomain)* or manage.windowsazure.com/*(yourdomain)*, you're indicating which tenant you want to sign in as from the beginning, and thus, Azure AD knows what branding to show.

Since custom branding is still in Preview, I would not be surprised to see updates to this behavior.