# Customize login page in Microsoft OpenId Connect / Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

The question was answered many times already but I am looking a way to customise login screen for multi-tenant web applications registered in Azure AD the way https://portal.azure.com does.

I am aware about custom login page for b2c apps documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview and company branding documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding.
The former uses b2clogin.com domain and an option to use MSA as external ID provider. The later applies branding of user's tenant and on the **password prompt** only.

portal.azure.com instead looks like a mix of both. It uses regular OpenId Connect v1 endpoints and redirects to

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
?resource=https%3a%2f%2fmanagement.core.windows.net%2f
&response_mode=form_post
&response_type=code+id_token
&scope=user_impersonation+openid
&client_id=c44b4083-3bb0-49c1-b47d-974e53cbdf3c
&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fportal.azure.com%2fsignin%2findex%2f%3ffeature.refreshtokenbinding%3dtrue
```

The **login prompt** however presents application logo and github login option similarly to b2c but allows to use MSA account like usual login.microsoftonline.com:

[image]

I am wondering if it is possible to do something similar for my own app. The similar question [Custom Branding for Login on a Azure AD Multi-Tenant App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43105050/custom-branding-for-login-on-a-azure-ad-multi-tenant-app) was asked a few years ago, and the only answer there suggests it's a feature of Microsoft owned apps. Even tho the answer was not accepted I'd trust Anton on this account. Is it still the case today?